# testing monaca backend only possible on device, why?

Tags: monaca

When I test my app on my device I'm able to connect to the backend user and collection features. Why isn't that working when I preview the app in the browser (Chrome)? Or is it possible and what should I do to fix this...

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [Monaca Backend API Reference Guide](https://docs.monaca.io/en/reference/monaca_api/cloud/), Monaca backend requires a phonegap plugin thus the browser does not have these installed and therefore you will not be able to access those systems.

Ultimately, there is nothing you can do other than to test in the app, although if you use the [Monaca Cloud IDE](https://monaca.io/cloud.html), you do gain a web interface to manage the backend.  It is very useful.

Hope this helps!